# Trying to find if an item exists in database table, if it doesn' t exist. add it

Tags: java, sql, database, select

I am trying to develop a program where you want to add a new book ( title, author, date,...)
but i do not want to add the author multiple times..
i want the program to check if the author already exists in the table, if not it will add him... here is my code :

```
public void insert_bk(String m, String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
    String sql="Select * from author where Full_Name='"+b+"'";
    System.out.println(sql);

    try {  
        opencn();
        Statement st=cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) { 
            String id=rs.getString("Author_ID");
            System.out.println(id);
            st.executeUpdate("INSERT into book (`Book_ID`,`Title`,`Author_ID`,`Date_of_release`,`Theme`,`Edition`)"+ "VALUES ('" + m+ "','" + a+ "','" + id+ "', '" + d+ "', '" + e+ "', '" + c+ "')");
        }  
    }
    catch(SQLException exp) {
        System.out.println(exp.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In this code it just checks if the Author exists and adds the book... how can i make the condition that if the author does not exist it will add him along with the book?

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The same way you're adding the book I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a while-loop you should put rs.next() into an if-statement. If the call returns false no author is present and it has to be inserted.

Comment: As Linus wrote you insert authors the same way you insert the books.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a conditional insert by adding the keyword IGNORE into the statement.  Depending on which SQL database you are using the answer is slightly different.  I'll demonstrate here the two ways for MySQL and sqlite, but of course there are  more.

For MySQL

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO authors VALUES(?,?...,?)
```

For SQLite

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO authors VALUES(?,?,...,?);
```

Comment: i dont have a problem with the insert... i am having a problem with the condition, if the author exists then insert book... if author does not exist... insert author and then new book... this is the problem i am having...

Comment: So I edited my answer to reflect what you are trying to do.  The revised answer shows how to insert the author, but will ignore the insert if the author already exists.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this stored procedure

```
declare @i int
Select @i=count(*) from author where Full_Name=@FullName
IF(@i < 1)
  BEGIN
  // INSERT 
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
String query = "Select * from author where Full_Name='"+b+"'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
SqlDataReader rdr;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (rdr.Read()) { // if you have an author
    //do your updation code here
}
else {
    //if rdr.Read() gives 0 which will be the case when our
    //author wont exist past the code for adding an author here
}
```